# PHP cURL code fails online but not on localhost. Please help!

Tags: php, json, curl

I cannot figure out why this code works locally on my PC (localhost) but not online on a public server? Can it be a PHP version issue? Thankful for all help!

```
$post_data = array('item_type_id' => '8', 'string_key' => 'Test Nyckel2', 'string_value' => 'Test Varde2', 'string_extra' => 'Test Extra', 'numeric_extra' => 'Test Numeric Extra', 'is_public' => true, 'is_public_for_contacts' => true);

    $post_data = json_encode(array('item' => $post_data), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

    $c = curl_init('http://example.com/items.json'); 

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'fb_cookie='.$fb_code);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

    curl_exec($c);

    curl_close($c);
```

Comment: Provide us with the errors, most probably your web server doesn't have the curl module. But it's just a guess.

Comment: Other cURL calls works fine. Like GET and DELETE. Strangly enough.

Comment: What about calls that *don't* work, what errors do they produce if any?

Comment: No errors the process that just not work.

Comment: You do not seem to be handling curl errors at all. See here how to do this : http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl_exec` returns FALSE if the request fails for any reason. You can then get the error codes and message with `curl_error()` and `curl_errno()`:

```
if (curl_exec($c) === FALSE) {
    die("Curl failed: " . curl_error($c));
}
```

Never assume that curl calls will succeed. Always check the returned value in case something did blow up. Even if curl's set up properly, a network glitch could've killed the connection, the remote server could be down, firewall's having a bad day, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using the options parameter in your json_encode() call.

However here is what PHP doc says (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
5.3.0 The options parameter was added.
```

So you PHP code is using an undefined constant, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT?

Answer (score 0):

Is the cURL Library installed on the server that isn't working?

If you can't tell, use the phpinfo(); function.

Comment: Yes, it is. Other cURL calls works fine. The only difference is that the cURL calls that does not work is sending along a JSON object. Can this be the problem?

Comment: The working server got PHP verion 5.3 and the none working got 5.2.

Comment: How about an IP restriction on the server you are trying to get data from?